# Can't install PHP 7.3: "release not found"

Tags: php, composer-php

I want to install php7.3. I use the following script.

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && \
    apt-get -y install software-properties-common && \
    add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install  php7.3 \
                        php7.3-mbstring
```

The error says:

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu eoan Release' does not have a Release file.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/dists/eoan/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I am using:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

The guide I followed was [How to install PHP (7, 7.2 or 7.3) on Ubuntu](https://thishosting.rocks/install-php-on-ubuntu/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your system is trying to use `eoan` distribution of Ubuntu, which is not yet released, so it's no wonder that packages for that distribution do not exist on this PPA.

You can manually change `eoan` to `bionic` in the relevant file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` and run `apt-get update && apt-get -y install php7.3 php7.3-mbstring` again.

Why is your system using `eoan` instead of `bionic`, I cannot answer.